# How to reverse video on Mac OS?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

i don't have a Final Cut.

Is there a way to reverse video ?

Some apps, or terminal utilites ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to flip the actual appearance of the video or are you trying to completely reverse the way it plays back?

Answer (score 0):

In Quicktime 7, you can hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>(Left Arrow)</kbd> to reverse playback.

Comment: 1 frame at a time? that is kind of lame.